# How do I create this query in LINQ to Entities

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have an `MVC` app using `Linq to Entities` and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to get this part of a query written. This is an excerpt from a `SQL Stored Procedure` that works. I know I can use the procedure but I'm trying to get  a better understanding of `LINQ`. The goal is to get the last Routing for a requisition and the ReqRoutingID is an identity filed so the last entry in the table is always the one I want.

```
SELECT
    h.ReqID,
    rr.RoutingSectionID
FROM LOG_ReqHeader h
JOIN dbo.Log_ReqRoutings rr
    ON  rr.ReqRoutingID = (
        SELECT TOP 1 r.ReqRoutingID
        FROM Log_ReqRoutings r1
        WHERE r1.ReqID = h.ReqID 
        ORDER BY r1.ReqRoutingID desc)
```

Comment: I think your query missing SELECT part

Comment: @Lazyberezovsky, I realize that I had not indicated which part I am having trouble with. It is the Join part that I am having trouble with. I edited the post to include the SELECT part so it makes more sense. Thanks.

Comment: Could you post your entities?

Comment: ReqRoutingID is a key of Log_RequRoutings table?

Comment: @Lazyberezovsky, I'm confused because you had posted an answer that worked but now the post says it has been deleted.

Comment: @AlanFisher undeleted, sorry - wanted to verify `First` and forgot to undelete back :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var query = from h in db.LOG_ReqHeader
            from rr in db.Log_RequRoutings
            where rr.ReqRoutingID == (from r1 in db.Log_RequRoutings
                                      where r1.Req == h.ReqID
                                      orderby r1.ReqRoutingID descending
                                      select r1).FirstOrDefault().ReqRoutingID
            select new { h.ReqID, rr.RoutingSectionID };
```

Comment: Sorry, don't remember now if `First` is supported by EF (`FirstOrDefault` is definitely supported). You can give it a try

Comment: If `FirstOrDefault()` returns `null` wont that give exception on accessing `ReqRoutingID` ?

Comment: @Magnus whole query is translated into SQL, so there will not be any exceptions here

Comment: This answer worked once I cleaned up things like removing the extra "u" from Log_RequRoutings. What confuses me is the fact that there are two from statements. This is the first time I have come across a statement like this.

Comment: @AlanFisher yes, there is no problem with several `from` statements. Actually it is the only way you can do join with conditions in Linq